# How 32-bit computer fetch data from memory

Tags: padding, 32bit-64bit, processor

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct var{
    
    
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    
};


int main()
{
    struct var r;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(r));
  
    return 0;
}
Output: 3
```

I know how 3 bytes of character type data are stored in memory with giving proper alignment.
[image]

But I am confused, while a 32-bit computer fetches data it is supposed to fetch 4 bytes at a time. If this statement is true then 1-byte padding should happen before storing `char a` `char b` and `char c`. Am I correct?

And In the case of a 64-bit computer 5-bytes need to be padded and then store `char a` `char b` and `char c`. And processor will fetch 8 bytes at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Note, I realized in the image I forgot to count the 0x000000 address, sorry.

this is a great question, I'm sorry if I explain concepts you're already familiar with, but just in case I will.

First of all, sadly, as with most things, it depends. I say this because 64 bit may not really mean the same between uses, this because it can mainly refer to the data bus, or the address bus, or both. That depends on your architecture, if you are using a computer, then most probably, pretty sure you are using 32 bit on both, the address bus, and the data bus. If you are working on an MCU, then it will depend a lot on the MCU and its architecture, maybe your addressing would be 16 bit but it's data 32.

That taken, lets focus on the address bus, having a 32 bit address bus, means that you can go to 2^32 different addresses, now I think here is where you got confused, each address is actually a byte, that's why a 32 bit computer, is limited to 4GB of ram, because 2^32 = 4,294,967,296. If each is a byte, then that would be 4GB.

Now, each word's length in the ram is defined by the data bus, as we said, most probable thing is it is also a 32 bit, so, this will allow us to fit 4 bytes, hence, each word will be made of 4 bytes. So in this case, our ram "grid" looks like this. Quick note, memory addressing is never really used nowadays. With byte addressing, words do not need to start/end the same as rows do.

[image]

Now, what happens with padding, well, first of all, all data types have a native size in C, this size ALSO depends on your architecture, some data types are made to use one word (4 bytes), some use 2 words (8 bytes) and some 1 byte. Remember the word size depends on the data bus size, in this case 32 bit data bus = 32/8 = 4 words. The char type uses only one byte. When you compile and run, the processor starts to allocate memory and keep track where everything goes, in this case for example, your padding doesn't matter, the processor knows it's free and will allocate something if needed. Remember also that words are not defined to a row in the ram, as long as they are successive, the cpu can ask for 4 continues bytes, maybe using the image above as a reference, from 0x00...02 to 0x00...05.

so for example, you can store in 0x0000, b in 0x0001, and a in 0x0002, then you can store a signed integer (typically 4 bytes in modern computers) from 0x0003-0x0006. The cpu keeps track that the integer is in 0x0003-0x0006, that c is in 0x0001 etc, and also that your struct is from 0x0000 to 0x0002

Comment: *Quick note, memory addressing is never really used nowadays.* - What are you talking about?  Did you mean **word** addressing isn't really used?  It is in DSPs, but yes all mainstream CPU architectures these days are byte-addressable.  (In word addressing, there wouldn't *be* addresses at all for the individual bytes.)